# Ошибка при отправки файла по FTP

Tags: java, ftp

Код FTP

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect("108.303.0.102", 112);
ftpClient.login("u1", "125789");
int replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
    System.out.println("Connection proper");
}

if(ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("share")) {
    System.out.println("Directory Change Succesfull");
}
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("H:/testFile.txt"));
BufferedInputStream inputStrean = new BufferedInputStream(input);
if(ftpClient.storeFile("testFile.txt", input)) {
    System.out.println("File Stored Successfully");
}
input.close();
inputStrean.close();
ftpClient.logout();
ftpClient.disconnect();
```

Ошибка

```
org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying.
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(Util.java:119)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(Util.java:151)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(Util.java:162)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:373)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:1360)
    at com.fs.ftp.FTPUsingFTPClientApache.startFTP(FTPUsingFTPClientApache.java:40)
    at com.fs.ftp.FTPUsingFTPClientApache.main(FTPUsingFTPClientApache.java:17)
```

Получаю исключение: `ftpClient.storeFile("testFile.txt", input)`

Comment: Вероятно, проблема в правах на запись в директорию.